# Como obtener el progreso y velocidad de descarga desde Java?

Tags: java

Encontré un [ejemplo](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url) para descargar un archivo http desde java

```
public class DescargaHttp {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public static void descargarArchivo(String URLArchivo, String Directorio)
            throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(URLArchivo);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");


            if (disposition != null) {

                int index = disposition.indexOf("NombreArchivo=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = URLArchivo.substring(URLArchivo.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        URLArchivo.length());
            }

            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            String saveFilePath = Directorio + File.separator + fileName;

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);



            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            System.out.println("Archivo Descargado");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No se encuentra el archivo. Codigo Servidor HTTP: " + responseCode);
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Hay alguna manera de como sacar la velocidad y el tamaño descargado (ejemplo 12.5 MB de 120 MB)

Intente imprimir el

```
System.out.println(bytesRead);
System.out.println(inputStream);
```

Sin embargo jamas había trabajado con las descargas en java y no tengo idea como puedo obtener esos datos, pensé en leer el tamaño del archivo con `Files.size(new File(filename).toPath())` mas no se si sea lo mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con el método `httpConn.getContentLengthLong()` para obtener el tamaño total si es que está disponible en el header de la conexión.

Para la velocidad me temo que tendrias que calcularla en cada iteración de lectura en el buffer en base a los bytes totales leídos y el tiempo total transcurrido.